# When I have completed the reviews, I still get the number in the top bar

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review, suggested-edits

So today I (unusually) reached the max (20) in the suggested edits queue.

[image]

As you can see, the orange box refers to the suggested edits queue - confirmed because when I click it goes to the suggested edits queue.

[image]

So I click on it, it takes me there and... I can't review any, I've already done all 20.

Could this be changed to reflect the current highest review queue length, EXCLUDING ones that have been completed. Right now, for me it always goes to the suggested edits queue and I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "why" is that there are still 4 edits needing to be reviewed. You can't review them - yet - but they're still there; if they're *still* around in a few hours, you'll be able to review them; if someone else gets to them first, the number will go down. The number exists to reflect what's left to do, not necessarily what *you* can do.

Note that if you earn 10K reputation, you'll see the number change to reflect the combined pending totals of *all* review queues - again, whether or not you're personally able to review them.

tl;dr: **the number is informational; it exists as long as there is information to be displayed.**

Comment: But why is it only the suggested edits review queue?

Comment: That queue is considered the most urgent - edits often make the difference between a problematic post and a great one.